# Discord.py run after close

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, python-asyncio

I am just trying to write a simple "send message" function using Discord.py but I am battling a lot.

If you comment out `send_something('second')` then this works perfectly. But if you use this function twice then you get the RuntimeWarning.

```
def send_something(message):
    client = discord.Client()
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        connection = await client.fetch_user(USER_ID)
        await connection.send(message)
        await client.close()

    client.run(TOKEN)

# You can run the first one, but you can't run both
send_something('first') 
send_something('second') # RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run.<locals>.runner' was never awaited
```

Then I tried making it an async function, adding await, in which case you now have to "wait" for the outside function in some way. So I did this:

```
async def send_something(message):
    client = discord.Client()
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        connection = await client.fetch_user(USER_ID)
        await connection.send(message)
        await client.close()

    await client.run(TOKEN)

# No error but no message gets sent
asyncio.ensure_future(send_something('first'))
asyncio.ensure_future(send_something('second'))
```

Now there is no error, but the messages never get sent. I'm guessing the script ends and "closes" before the work is finished?

Any idea how I can write some kind of "send message" function? Because all the discord.py examples I find are based on waiting for "events" which is not what I need here.

Comment: If you just need a function to send messages to someone, you shouldn't really use discord.py at all. just use discord's raw API and send the message to the person directly

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to create a post request to [discord api](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference):

Code:

```py
headers = {'Authorization': f"Bot {YOUR_BOT_TOKEN}"}

dm = requests.post(
  url='https://discord.com/api/v6/users/@me/channels',
  headers=headers, 
  json={"recipient_id": RECEIVER_ID}
).json()

requests.post(
  f"https://discord.com/api/v6/channels/{dm['id']}/messages",
  headers=headers, 
  json={"content": "Hello!"}
)
```

`RECEIVER_ID` is your [snowflake ID](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#snowflakes), or the ID of whoever you wish to DM.

More Information:

- [How to create a DM](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#create-dm)
- [How to create a message](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30889211)